# Learning Laravel: Seeding

Tags: database, laravel, seeding

I am trying a seed right now, but when I tried it. It just shows an error on the command prompt that it cannot find the target class. And I already made sure the files are in the database/seeds directory. Here are my codes. Please help.

UserTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
  /**
  * Seed the application's database.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function run()
  {
    // $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
    DB::table("users")->delete();

    User::create(array(
        "name" => "Chris Sevilleja",
        "username" => "sevilayha",
        "email" => "chris@scotch.io",
        "password" => Hash::make("awesome"),
    ));
  }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Seed the application's database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function run()
   {
     Eloquent::unguard();

     $this->call("UserTableSeeder");
   }
 }
```

Comment: `User::create` You need to use `use App\User` after your namespace

Comment: @kerbholz can you explain in detail? I don't really understand

Comment: Since you didn't include a detailed error description I was assuming that the `User` model can not be found, because the script doesn't know where to find it. (I just realized there is no namespace in your script, so my comment might have been misleading). Add `use App\User` before `class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder`. Or/And maybe add the error description to your question

Comment: it finally worked, just like you said. After I do composer autoloader, it really got an error on the User. Thanks again dude. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new seed you need to reload composer autoloader

Run the command `composer dump-autoload`